# Motorised fader

Tags: pro-tools

I’m looking for a single motorised fader for Protools.
I am aware of Alphatrack and Faderport but I was hoping for something even simplier.
Just one fader no pans or transport buttons etc.
Does this product exist?

Answer (score 1):

@jacob,

I just found this (http://vmeter.net/). Not motorized, but very interesting, and inexpensive.

Have fun making sound for movies,

E. Santiago

Comment: Nice one, great find!


Answer (score 0):

What are you using it for? As a stereo master controller, or for automation of a single channel?

Answer (score 0):

Automation of a single channel

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to control one channel I have heard good things about the Presonus FaderPort http://www.presonus.com/products/FaderPort

I doubt you can get much simpler since it literally is one fader and a few other important and frequently used buttons.

Never tried it myself but since its by Presonus I would trust it quality wise, I have never had anything in the past by them that I thought was below par.

Answer (score 0):

+1 for the Faderport. Sounds like just what you need.